# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Tacotron2: size mismatch for embedding.weight

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, text-to-speech

I am training a tacotron 2 notebook with new dataset. But while training it gives error for size mismatched.

```
FP16 Run: False
Dynamic Loss Scaling: True
Distributed Run: False
cuDNN Enabled: True
cuDNN Benchmark: False
Downloading...
From: https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?export=download&confirm=kZ1A&id=1c5ZTuT7J08wLUoVZ2KkUs_VdZuJ86ZqA
To: /content/tacotron2/pretrained_model
100%|██████████| 113M/113M [00:00<00:00, 151MB/s]
Warm starting model from checkpoint 'pretrained_model'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e8a871a0e98d> in <module>
      5 print('cuDNN Benchmark:', hparams.cudnn_benchmark)
      6 train(output_directory, log_directory, checkpoint_path,
----> 7       warm_start, n_gpus, rank, group_name, hparams, log_directory2)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in load_state_dict(self, state_dict, strict)
   1603         if len(error_msgs) > 0:
   1604             raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
-> 1605                                self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
   1606         return _IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys, unexpected_keys)
   1607 

    RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Tacotron2:
        size mismatch for embedding.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([148, 512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([88, 512]).
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where are you getting the weights from? And how are you downloading the model? Are you properly specifying the correct model name? Your error suggests that the dimensions of the weights you have don't match what's expected for the model you're using